# How to bind process to a certain numa node in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numa

I'm using `multiprocessing.Pool`, and I want to bind first half of the processes in the Pool to `numa node 0`, and another half to `numa node 1`, how can I do it in python? If it's not available with `multiprocessing.Pool`'s API, are there any alternative ways?